# FirebaseStorage issue downloading data into memory (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Thanks to the major update in Firebase, I'm switching the image hosting for my app from AWS to the now included GS Storage in Firebase.
I've already imported all necessary pods, this app already do successfully upload images to assigned buckets, but the problem is when I want to download to memory images stored, and the app is crashing, debugging I found the following error in my FIRStorageReference object: "use of undeclared type 'FirebaseStorage'"
I'm importing the Firebase header to the VC where the function is located.

```
func getImage(imageName: String) -> UIImage {
    let imageRef = kBucketRef.child(imageName) 
    print(imageRef) 
    var imageData: NSData? 
    var image: UIImage? 
    imageRef.dataWithMaxSize(200 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in 
        if (error != nil) { 
        imageData = data 
        image = UIImage(data: imageData!) 
        } else { 
            print(error?.localizedDescription) 
        } 
   }
    return image! 
}
```

later when trying to display image in: image.image = getImage(imageName) is called it throws the mentioned error in return image!

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>
> Printing description of imageRef: expression produced error:
>   /var/folders/9q/g2rz2_hj15548cf15yrxz37c0000gn/T/lldb/1645/expr11.swift:1:46:
>   error: use of undeclared type 'FirebaseStorage'
>   $__lldb__DumpForDebugger(Swift.UnsafePointer< FirebaseStorage.FIRStorageReference >(bitPattern:
>   0x11d028fa0).memory)
>                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /var/folders/9q/g2rz2_hj15548cf15yrxz37c0000gn/T/lldb/1645/expr11.swift:1:45:
>   note: while parsing this '<' as a type parameter bracket
>   $__lldb__DumpForDebugger(Swift.UnsafePointer(bitPattern:
>   0x11d028fa0).memory)

The output from 'print(imageRef)' prints the GS reference (gs://project-xxxxxx...) but the '.dataWithMaxSize()' fails

Thanks in advance

---

(days later)
Ok, here is a workaround since the FIRStorage methods are not modifying vars in a separated function for later return:

```
let bucket: String = "gs://mystoragetesterxxxxxx.appspot.com"


func getImage() {

    let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
    let storageRef = storage.referenceForURL(bucket)
    let path = storageRef.child("photo.jpg")
    print(path)
    path.dataWithMaxSize(1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }

}
```

Now getImage it's a void function, but it works

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this isn't just an issue where you're declaring an optional type:

`var image: UIImage?`

Then calling an async function

`imageRef.dataWithMaxSize...`

and then without waiting for it, returning an implicitly unwrapped optional?

`return image!`

Seems to me like since image is nil, you're "unexpectedly unwrapping a nil" that is pretty much relying on a race condition to succeed.

I'd try something more like:

```
var image: UIImage? 
imageRef.dataWithMaxSize(200 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in 
    if (error != nil) { 
        return UIImage(data: data!)!
    } else { 
        print(error?.localizedDescription) 
    } 
}
```

In general though, wrapping an async call and trying to make it synchronous is a bad idea (unless you implement something like promises)--you should just use the async call to then update the UI element back on the main thread.

Comment: Changed the function according to your suggestion and it throws nil, the stored file path is correct, there is a file there but it still doesn't assign it to "data", the bucket is configured to be public.
It doesn't triggers the (error != nil) condition, it just don't download the image

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
```

then the function

```
    func getImage(imageName: String) -> UIImage {
        let gsReference = storage.referenceForURL(imageName!)

        print(imageRef) 
        var imageData: NSData? 
        var image: UIImage? 
        let downloadTask = gsReference.dataWithMaxSize(200 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in 
            if (error != nil) { 
            //imageData = data 
            //image = UIImage(data: imageData!) 

             let image = UIImage.init(data: data!)

            } else { 
                print(error?.localizedDescription) 
            } 

          downloadTask.observeStatus(.Resume) { (snapshot) -> Void in
                print("Downloading has started")


            }
      }
    return image! 
}
```

Then you see on log if the download has started.

Comment: Before the download task I can print the Storage reference full path: gs://project-xxxxxx163293.appspot.com/images/xxxxxx.jpg, so the reference is ok  
In dataWithMaxSize:completion I've added a print("dataWithMaxSize running") statement before the if, and then the next console output is the "found nil" error in the return image line, I'm thinking the task is not running and when the image:UIImage? gets called from return it's nil and therefore the error.